# PHP Get Page Load Stats - How to measure php script execution / load time

Tags: php, time, load, pageload

What I have in the header:

```
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
```

What I have in the footer:

```
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo 'Page generated in ' . $total_time . ' seconds.';
```

Output: Page generated in 1292008977.54 seconds.

Can someone please help me figure out why the result is not right?? I am using PHP5.

Comment: you're overwriting $start somewhere

Comment: I just ran your code above with a `sleep(2);` between the 'header' and 'footer' and got `Page generated in 2.0055 seconds.` So its something in the middle of your script probably. (which Col. Shrapnel wrote while I was running my test .. )

Comment: My code nor the code listed in the first 2 answers works for me. It must be something in the rest of my script that is causing the issues. I did notice that the start time variable is not existant in my footer file.

Comment: are you including the footer file inside a function?

Comment: variable scope issue? http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`microtime()` returns the current **Unix timestamp** with ***microseconds***.  i don't see any math there that does the conversion from **microseconds** to seconds.

`microtime(true)` returns the time as a float in ***seconds***

Comment: yikes.  i totally blew right past that.  reading is fundamental :)

Answer (score 8):

Seeing how this is the first result in Google I thought I'd share my solution to this problem. Put this at the top of your page:

```
$startScriptTime=microtime(TRUE);
```

And then put this code at the bottom of your page:

```
$endScriptTime=microtime(TRUE);
$totalScriptTime=$endScriptTime-$startScriptTime;
echo "\n\r".'<!-- Load time: '.number_format($totalScriptTime, 4).' seconds -->';
```

When you view source of a page you can see the load time in a comment on the last line of your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this simple function to avoid the variable scope issue:

```
<?php

function timer()
{
    static $start;

    if (is_null($start))
    {
        $start = microtime(true);
    }
    else
    {
        $diff = round((microtime(true) - $start), 4);
        $start = null;
        return $diff;
    }
}

timer();

echo 'Page generated in ' . timer() . ' seconds.';
```

Comment: OMG will someone of these keen helpers learn **microtime(true)** at last?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: My wrong, just rewrote ATLChris's solution into a function on the first approach... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: whole function becomes obsolete. it's just `$start=microtime(1); echo microtime(1) - $start`; no use for the function here.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I just don't understand your problem with the function. It uses a local static variable to hold the start time, so you can call it from anywhere in the script.

Comment: it's not my problem but the op's one. I am smart enough to calculate time without no lame functions

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I think you need some reading on [static variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static).

Comment: omg. I know this shit already for ten years. but one don't need no static variables nor stupid functions for this task. just usual global variable. And a little brains to not to rewrite it. that's all

Comment: @Col Shrapnel: I think it's not a good advice to use global variable for anything (maybe static variables are as bad as global variables, but at least this function protects from accidental overwriting).

Comment: I can't believe you still don't understand. You're picking distinct words but missing whole point. Read my lips: **No. Function. Needed.** At all. No function. No scope variables, static or global. No function. Do you copy? One can have the same result with o function. With just a regular variable. It is also called 'global', but it has nothing to do with 'global' keyword. it is just the name for the regular variable from the global scope. You're using dozens of them. Everyone does. Nothing bad in it. Just a variable. That's all. though, I doubt you got it. Anyway - good luck

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I agree on you that there is no need for any user-defined function in a ten line script...

Answer (score 2):

One liner for the `footer`, which returns `seconds` as `float`:

```
echo number_format(microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"],4);
```

You do not need to put anything at the start of your script, as `$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]` takes care to capture this time when the PHP script starts...  Then you only need to calculate at the very end of the PHP how much time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use something like this.  Makes it easy to time multiple code blocks without juggling variable names and such.  sessions have to be enabled.

```
function code_timer ($name) {

    $mtime = explode(' ',microtime());
    $time = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];

    //determine if we're starting the timer or ending it
    if ($_SESSION["timer-$name"]) {
      $stime=$_SESSION["timer-$name"];
      unset($_SESSION["timer-$name"]);
      return ($time - $stime);
    } else {
      $_SESSION["timer-$name"]=$time;
      return(true);  
    }
}
```

usage:

```
code_timer ('a');
//do stuff
echo "page generated in " . code_timer('a');
```

Comment: This isn't going to fix his problem, there's a time conversion not happening here.  See my answer.

Comment: @ Daniel Bingham: Your answer is wrong, the above code works fine, and you don't have to do anything to microtime() output as you're suggesting.  His problem is that the start variable is getting overwritten in the middle of his script.  The guys code works fine if you just copy and paste it.  The problem is whatever he has between the code which isn't posted.

Comment: @shrapnel, ok troll.  Try posting something useful for once, in this example maybe its not a lot of use, but if you try hard you can probably think of a use for it.

Comment: @shrapnel, The OP logic works perfectly, but the implementation broken, because the guy is unsetting his start value somewhere in his code.  Putting it in a function, which specifically creates a variable that likely hasnt been used elsewhere ("timer-$name"), solves the problem.  There IS something to post, because his code didn't work for him.  This is a simple alternative.  I realize the code he posted 'works' stand alone, I mentioned it above.  Read the things and actually think before you get all high and mighty.

Answer (score 1):

```
$page_loadtime_in_millisec = ($page_loadtime / 1000);
echo '<pre>Page Infor:
Page Load Time : ' . $page_loadtime.' <b>Microseconds</b><br/>
Page Load Time : ' . $page_loadtime_in_millisec.' <b>Milliseconds</b><br/>
Page Load Time : ' . number_format(($page_loadtime_in_millisec/1000),18) . ' <b>Seconds</b></pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Header

```
<?php

$starttime = explode(' ', microtime());
$starttime = $starttime[1] + $starttime[0];

?>
```

and this in your footer

```
<html><center>Page generated in <?php $load = microtime();print (number_format($load,2));?> seconds. <?php
$loadtime = explode(' ', microtime()); $loadtime = $loadtime[0]+$loadtime[1]-$starttime; echo 'Peak memory usage: ',round(memory_get_peak_usage()/1048576, 2), 'MB';
?></center></html>
```

this will tell you how long it took your sites page to generate and how much Memory was used to load the page

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with variable scope. You set your $start variable in the header, but in footer, this variable will be empty. So $total_time would just be current time - 0, giving you the current time.

A solution is to use php's GLOBALS. In the header:

```
$GLOBALS['time_start'] = microtime(true);
```

And in the footer:

```
$total_time = round(($finish - $GLOBALS['time_start']), 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using microtime in every single page, what i would do is to insert microtime into $_REQUEST and then subtract that time from the current time inside a function and set that function to be called when the script execution is terminated using:

`register_shutdown_function ( 'Your_function_name' );`

I think that it is useful to use a global script which will be included at the beginning of every script / class throughout the application, it helps me in handling errors, managing sessions, etc...

Adding microtime to $_REQUEST would be the first line in that script and you can include your terminating function there too.