# How to know php script load time hosted locally

Tags: php

I have a website developed with `PHP` from scratch, and I want to know the load time of my php script (my page) in localhost.

is there any method or tools to check that ? I try to use `Performance` on `Google Chrome`, but it's very hard to understand, and with some search on Google I found the `firebug` plugins of firefox, but it's deleted.

is there any solution ?

Comment: check you browser network tab.make sure you have enable `persistent log` option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231153/show-load-time-on-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want the mesure the loading time browser-side, as Madhawa commented, you can view it in the `network` tab of chrome's developer tools :

[image]

If you want the exact execution time of your script, it should be done server-side by checking the time before and after the script. Daniels link should point you to the right direction.

Comment: The `Time` return the script load time ?

Comment: It's the time between the request and the reception of the response, including the script's execution time, if it's synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, that can help me, because I want to know how long my page take, to optimize on the local (in the past I need to hosted it and using online testing)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
echo $start;
?>
```

Try this